# Problems with Ajax/Javascript creating buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

This is a javascript function I have to create buttons dynamically base on what is in a textfile during onload. The buttons cant seem to be created at all although it is able to read the file and I make use of alert messages to check if var button is correct.

```
function createButtons(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("1");
      $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/SSAD/type.txt',
        dataType : "text",
        success : function (filecontent) {
          var lines=filecontent.split('\n');
          $.each(lines, function() {
            if (this!='') {
              var button='<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-inverse active" data-toggle="button tooltip" title="Click this to enable/disable viewing of'+this+'" onclick="toggleVisibility('+"'"+this+"'"+')">'+this+'</button>';
              $("#crisisButtons").append(button);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="crisisButtons"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = createButtons();</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `success` function fires?

Comment: Pretty sure it does as I added an alert(this) within the if loop and it display what is inside the text file.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning an event handler, you are calling it. The function createButtons is being called right away and whatever it returns is being assigned to window.onload.

```
window.onload = createButtons();
```

needs to be

```
window.onload = createButtons;
```

What you really should be using is [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Another issue you have is you are using DOMReady and onload. Two different events that do different things! Pick one, do not use both.

Change your code so it is just

```
$(function() {
    alert("1");
  $.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/SSAD/type.txt',
    dataType : "text",
    success : function (filecontent) {
      var lines=filecontent.split('\n');
      $.each(lines, function() {
        if (this!='') {
          var button='<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-inverse active" data-toggle="button tooltip" title="Click this to enable/disable viewing of'+this+'" onclick="toggleVisibility('+"'"+this+"'"+')">'+this+'</button>';
          $("#crisisButtons").append(button);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

and use an error handler on the Ajax call to make sure that is not being triggered.

---

**EDIT**

And why nothing shows up

```
$("#crisisButtons").append(button);  <-- ID selector
<div class="crisisButtons"></div>    <-- class name
```

So change the id selector to a class and you get

```
$(function() {
    alert("1");
  $.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/SSAD/type.txt',
    dataType : "text",
    success : function (filecontent) {
      var lines=filecontent.split('\n');
      $.each(lines, function() {
        if (this!='') {
          var button='<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-inverse active" data-toggle="button tooltip" title="Click this to enable/disable viewing of'+this+'" onclick="toggleVisibility('+"'"+this+"'"+')">'+this+'</button>';
          $(".crisisButtons").append(button);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: How will window.onload = createButtons; work on the code you have suggested?? Or am I suppose to create an event listener to for the code?

Comment: There is no need for the onload if you are using the DOM ready code. The last code block by itself should be fine.

Comment: I have tried it but somehow my buttons are still not displaying. It is also not displaying the alert msg I used.

Comment: Did you add an error handler to the Ajax call? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: And I just posted why nothing shows up.

Comment: I've noticed that error too and changed it but it is not working still. Thanks for the help thus far.